# onClick() simple issue

Tags: android, onclick

I have a (simple) problem of logic with `onClick()`.

My code looks like that.

```java
Myobject myobject ;
onCreate() {
    ...
    myobject = ... ;
    Button button=...
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
}
```

In my `onClick()`, i notice i can't have access to myobject. Its value is always null (but not outside `onClick()`.

So, my question is simple. How to access to myobject inside `onClick()` ? (and without set myobject to final).

Thanks for answering !!

Comment: post your full source code...it help to understand....

Comment: You should preview your posts before you post them... because this formatting is absolutely terrible.

Answer (score 1):

You can access class level variables like,

```
YourClassName.this.classLevelVariableName.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial formatted code.
In my xml layout, i have a listview and some buttons at the bottom.

If i launch this code and click on my button, i will have the following result :

Asu : thenameimlookingfor

Asu : null

Asu : null

```
public class AlertSetupEditorActivity extends Activity{

private ListView listView2;
AlertSetupEditorAdapter adapter;

AlertSetUpObject asu = new AlertSetUpObject();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.alertsetupeditorlistview);  

    asu = getAsu();
    Log.d("debug","Asu :"+asu.getName());

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_gauche);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("debug","Asu :"+asu.getName());
                    Log.d("debug","Asu: "+AlertSetupEditorActivity.this.asu.getName());

    }
});


   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell as your code is not formatted correctly in your question but I will take a stab at the answer being the following.

If you reference your MyObject fully, such as `myActivity.this.myobject` you should be able to access the variable. From code within an activity you can access the activities 'this' by prefixing it with the activities class name.

Answer (score 0):

Check out how I have my Context ctx setup this is what you are looking for. You will also probably need to do some threading work depending on how it is used.

```
public class WineSearch extends Activity {

    private static String[] names;
    private static float[] ratings;
    private static int[] ids;

    ListView lv;
    Context ctx;
    TextView searchHeader;
    ProgressDialog prgDiag;
    Spinner spn;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ctx = this;

        searchHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SearchHeader);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.WineListView);
        spn = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ListSpin);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.list_choice, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item); 
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spn.setAdapter(adapter);
        spn.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

          }     
        });

        prgDiag = new ProgressDialog(this);
        prgDiag.setCancelable(false);

        this.refreshList();
    }
```